# Menú dinámico en PrimeFaces

Tags: java, primefaces

Buenas tardes, tengo una consulta con respecto a la creación de un menú y sub-menú  en PrimeFaces JSF.

En mi base de datos está estructurado de la siguiente forma. La tabla `menu` está compuesta por:

- `idMenu(int)`
- `codMenu(varchar)`
- `nomMenu(varchar)`
- `link(varchar)`
- `estado(char)`
- `idSubMenu(int)`

La tabla `submenu` está compuesta por:

- `idSubMenu(int)`
- `codSubmenu(varchar)`
- `nomSubMenu(varchar)`
- `estado(char)`

¿Cómo podría mostrar el menú con sus respectivos sub-menús?

La estructura de la base de datos es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tal como está la pregunta es confusa, comenzando porque el modelo está muy mal. Entonces edita esta y mejor pregunta por el modelo, una vez lo tengas listo abre una nueva pregunta para la implementación en java.

Comment: De acuerdo con tu diagrama, un submenú tiene varios menús. Es decir `│Menu├*──────1┤SubMenu│`, lo cual no corresponde con el menú con sus respectivos submenús. La clave foránea debería estar en la tabla `submenu`. Tal vez quieras ver [*Clave foránea - Wiki*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clave_for%C3%A1nea).

Answer (score 1):

La relación está invertida, la tabla padre debe ser Menu y la tabla hija SubMenu.

En todo caso los menú siempre son candidatos perfectos para usar tablas recursivas.

```
---------------
| Menu        |
---------------
| MenuId      | ---|
| NomMenu     |    |  
| PadreMenuId | >--|
---------------
```

De tal manera que en una misma tabla tienen menus y submenus en tantos niveles como sea necesario.

Eventualmente, dependiendo de otros detalles de tu modelo de Menu, puede que para usar esta estrategia debe tener como mínimo un menú creado, el padre de todos y este existiria solo para que todo lo demás funcione.

```
-----------------------------------------
| MenuId | NomMenu        | PadreMenuId |
-----------------------------------------
|    0   | "MenuPadre"    | NULL        |
-----------------------------------------
|    1   | "MenuHijo"     | 0           |
-----------------------------------------
|    2   | "MenuHijo2"    | 0           |
-----------------------------------------
|    3   | "MenuPadre2"   | NULL        |
-----------------------------------------
|    4   | "MenuHijo2.1"  | 3           |
-----------------------------------------
|    5   | "MenuHijo2.2"  | 3           |
-----------------------------------------
|    6   | "MenuHijoLv2.1"| 5           |
-----------------------------------------
|    7   | "MenuHijoLv2.2"| 5           |
-----------------------------------------
```

Lo cual permitiría tener una estructura como esta:

- MenuPadre

  - MenuHijo
  - MenuHijo2
- MenuPadre2

  - MenuHijo2.1
  - MenuHijo2.2

    - MenuHijoLv2.1
    - MenuHijoLv2.2